# Tag a common friend and restrict someone - what happens?

Tags: facebook

Accounts: Me, Vic and King - all friends in Facebook

I post on my timeline and tag *Vic* and I restrict *King*. Is it possible that my post will show on King's Timeline since he's not restricted from Vic's account?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, it will not show on King's profile, because it is posted by you and King is restricted by you for this post.